# How do I connect the LEGO Powered Up remote control?

Tags: powered-up

I'm trying to use the Powered Up remote control to control my new train set, but it doesn't seem to work. Is there some process that I need to follow to connect or pair the remote with the Smarthub?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Powered Up system uses Bluetooth for control, so the remote needs to be paired with the Smarthub. To accomplish the pairing between the Powered Up remote and the Smarthub, you simply press the green buttons on both devices at the same time as shown in the instructions and [in this review by Beyond the Brick](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e7OLXr1USfg):

[image: proper pairing gif]

If the pairing process works correctly, both devices should have their lights lit up in the same color.