# Can Lego Remote Control 88010 control Lego Technic Hub 88012?

Tags: technic, compatibility, remote-control, bluetooth, powered-up

I have been exploring the new Bluetooth Technic smart hubs with the Control+ app and PoweredUp app. I would like to also use a physical remote.

I have the Technic smart hubs that come with the [Liebherr 9800](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=42100-1). I see this hub with different IDs on Bricklink ([88012](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=88012-1) and [bb0961c01](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=bb0961c01)).

Will the [train remote 88010](https://www.lego.com/en-us/product/remote-control-88010) work with the [Technic smart hubs 88012 aka bb0961c01](https://www.lego.com/en-us/product/technic-hub-88012)?

I see this [how-to-connect](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/10127/how-do-i-connect-the-lego-powered-up-remote-control) question, but that is to the [train hub 88009](https://www.lego.com/en-us/product/hub-88009).

Comment: Just to make things a little more clear - 88012 is number used to represent a Technic hub as a set (this is what you can buy directly from online LEGO store) and bb0961c01 is ID used to identify Technic Hub as a part (which is what comes inside a sealed set). So technically, bb0961c01 should be part of 88012 set. Not sure why this relationship hasn't been done for this particular case yet, since such approach has been used for other PU parts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No. I got the 42099 4x4 Off-roader recently, as well as the 60198 Cargo train. The monster truck didn't come with a physical remote, so I needed the app for it, unlike the cargo train which had both remote and app too.

The monster truck used a control system called Control+, while the train used another one called PoweredUP. I already felt it wouldn't work.

It wouldn't. I tried both of my PoweredUP remotes on the truck, but no response.  I tried them on both my Cargo Train and Passenger Train and they worked fine. They just didn't work on the monster truck.

And Lego never explicitly told us that they were compatible with eachother.

Comment: Thank you for those references!

Comment: @Jeff you are welcome! Do not forget to click the checkmark near my answer to mark it as accepted!

Comment: Technic hub has 4 ports/output, while train hub just 2. Now I wonder how can remote controller (88010), which can only operate two ports. knows which outputs it should actually control on Technic hub.

Comment: @Alex Oh, that corcerns me. Try looking [here](https://lan.lego.com/news/overview/powered-up-afol-community-answers-r146/) and seeing if there's any other info about the remote.

Comment: @mindstormsboi Technic hub wasn't released by the time those answers have been published.

Comment: @Jeff turns out I was wrong, it actually **doesn't** work. I will update my answer.

Comment: @mindstormsboi what do y'all think about this reference: https://lan.lego.com/news/overview/a-message-from-the-powered-up-team-r260/ from May 29 2020 says the "TECHNIC™ HUB (88012)" - "Connects via Bluetooth to the LEGO® Powered Up app and the Control handset". Does "Control handset" mean the train remote 88010? I should just buy the train already. :)

Comment: @Jeff We have more evidence that it works than that it doesn't, so I guess you're right??

Comment: Finally found clear evidence! https://youtu.be/hLbr4si2Qfs

Answer (score 3):

I got a 42099 4x4 X-treme Off-Roader too, and found that Power UP App (current version is 3.6.0) can connect to the Technic smart hub. Click Bluetooth button in Create Mode, and then press the green button on hub. Enjoy yourself:)

Comment: didnt notice that...